# Object reference null on physical Android device when injecting AutoMapper dependency in a Maui app

Tags: dependency-injection, automapper, maui

**Problem:**
I am developing a Maui app using an MVVM design pattern with SQLite for persistent storage on the device. I'm also using the CommunityToolkit.MVVM library. The app runs fine in the emulator, but when running it on a physical Android device, I encounter an issue related to the injection of the AutoMapper dependency.

When I run the app on a physical Android device, I receive an "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" error. Upon debugging, I found that the property oFoo (the source generated observable property) is null, which should not be the case. Interestingly, when running on the emulator, oFoo is not null.

**Code:**
I have a `MauiProgram.cs` file that sets up the app, configures fonts, and registers services, including the AutoMapper:

```cs
// MauiProgram.cs

namespace SomeNamespace
{
    public static class MauiProgram
    {
        public static MauiApp CreateMauiApp()
        {
            var builder = MauiApp.CreateBuilder();
            ConfigureApp(builder);
            ConfigureServices(builder.Services);
            return builder.Build();
        }

        private static void ConfigureApp(MauiAppBuilder builder)
        {
            builder
                .UseMauiApp<App>()
                .ConfigureFonts(FontsConfiguration.ConfigureFonts)

#if DEBUG
                .Logging.AddDebug();
#endif
        }

        private static void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddSingleton<SQLiteAsyncConnection>(sp =>
            {
                return new SQLiteAsyncConnection(Constants.DatabasePath, Constants.Flags);
            });
            services.AddSingleton<SQLiteService>();
            // Register AutoMapper
            services.AddSingleton<IMapper>(AutoMapperConfiguration.CreateMapper());
            ViewModelRegistration.RegisterViewModels(services);
            PageRegistration.RegisterPages(services);
        }
    }
}
```

The AutoMapper configuration is defined in `AutoMapperConfiguration.cs`:

```cs
// AutoMapperConfiguration.cs

namespace SomeNamespace.Configuration
{
    public static class AutoMapperConfiguration
    {
        public static IMapper CreateMapper()
        {
            var mapperConfig = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
            {
                cfg.AddProfile<MappingProfile>();
            });
            return mapperConfig.CreateMapper();
        }
    }
}
```

The mapping profile is defined in `MappingProfile.cs`:

```cs
// MappingProfile.cs

namespace SomeNamespace.Configuration
{
    public class MappingProfile : Profile
    {
        public MappingProfile()
        {
            CreateMap<ObservableFoo, Foo>().ReverseMap();
        }
    }
}
```

In my `MyFoosViewModel.cs` file, I inject the `SQLiteService` and `IMapper` instances:

```cs
// MyFoosViewModel.cs

namespace SomNamespace.ViewModels
{
    public partial class MyFoosViewModel : BaseViewModel
    {
        [ObservableProperty]
        ObservableFoo oFoo = new();

        private readonly SQLiteService _databaseService;
        private readonly IMapper _mapper;

        // AutoMapper instance for mapping between ObservableFoo and Foo.
        public IMapper Mapper => _mapper;

        public FooViewModel(SQLiteService databaseService, IMapper mapper)
        {
            Title = "Foo Details";
            _databaseService = databaseService;
            _mapper = mapper;
        }

        // Other methods...
    }
}
```

Additional classes and code can be found in this [Gist](https://gist.github.com/CRAMAR/494b773eec1f0861c5e547e0f5342abe) for reference.

The issue seems to be related to the injection of the AutoMapper dependency when running the app on a physical Android device. I would appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this problem.

Thank you!

Comment: https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Dependency-injection.html#asp-net-core